# How to distinguish calling a c library function from making a system call?

Tags: c, pipe, system-calls, libc

There is the C library function [pipe(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pipe) and the kernel (system call) [pipe(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).
Both have the same signature and should be used like this (same include header):

```
#include <unistd.h>
int fds[2];
pipe(fds);
```

Will this code call pipe(3) or pipe(2)?
How can I decide whether I want to use libc or a system call?
If pipe(3) and pipe(2) are the same, how do I know that?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this code call pipe(3) or pipe(2)?

It will call `pipe(3)`.

There is *no way* to call the system call *directly* from `C`, you either

- have to call libc wrapper for such system call (if one is provided), or
- use `syscall(2)` to "stuff" the right arguments into the right registers before executing architecture-appropriate system call instruction, or
- provide your own assembly wrapper which will do the same, or
- use inline `__asm__` to do the same.

Comment: Do you have a reference (to documentation)? Is this true for all libc/syscalls with same name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a distinction where there isn't one. Your code will call the `pipe` library function, which is just a wrapper around the `pipe` system call. It's not an either/or. The section 3 manual page is from the POSIX programmer's manual, and the section 2 manual page is Linux-specific.

Comment: Is unistd.h a libc, posix or linux header?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct: you _can_ execute `pipe(2)` (or any other) system call without going through the `pipe(3)` libc wrapper, and these two _are_ distinct.